# Producing same graph from raw and summarized data

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, stacked, stackedbarseries

#### Same plot from raw and summarized data

For the following data structure

```
dsN<-data.frame(
  id=rep(1:100, each=4),
  yearF=factor(rep(2001:2004, 100)),
  attendF=sample(1:8, 400, T, c(.2,.2,.15,.10,.10, .20, .15, .02))
)
dsN[sample(which(dsN$yearF==2001), 5), "attendF"]<-NA
dsN[sample(which(dsN$yearF==2002), 10), "attendF"]<-NA
dsN[sample(which(dsN$yearF==2003), 15), "attendF"]<-NA
dsN[sample(which(dsN$yearF==2004), 20), "attendF"]<-NA

attcol8<-c("Never"="#4575b4",
           "Once or Twice"="#74add1",
           "Less than once/month"="#abd9e9",
           "About once/month"="#e0f3f8",
           "About twice/month"="#fee090",
           "About once/week"="#fdae61",
           "Several times/week"="#f46d43",
           "Everyday"="#d73027")
dsN$attendF<-factor(dsN$attendF, levels=1:8, labels=names(attcol8))
head(dsN,13)

   id yearF              attendF
1   1  2001      About once/week
2   1  2002     About once/month
3   1  2003      About once/week
4   1  2004                 <NA>
5   2  2001 Less than once/month
6   2  2002      About once/week
7   2  2003      About once/week
8   2  2004   Several times/week
9   3  2001        Once or Twice
10  3  2002      About once/week
11  3  2003                 <NA>
12  3  2004        Once or Twice
13  4  2001   Several times/week
```

we can obtain a series of a stacked bar charts

```
require(ggplot2)
# p<- ggplot( subset(dsN,!is.na(attendF)), aes(x=yearF, fill=attendF)) # leaving NA out of
p<- ggplot( dsN, aes(x=yearF, fill=attendF))  #  keeping NA in calculations
p<- p+ geom_bar(position="fill")
p<- p+ scale_fill_manual(values = attcol8,
                         name="Response category" )
p<- p+ scale_y_continuous("Prevalence: proportion of total",
                          limits=c(0, 1),
                          breaks=c(.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1))
p<- p+ scale_x_discrete("Waves of measurement",
                        limits=as.character(c(2000:2005)))
p<- p+ labs(title=paste0("In the past year, how often have you attended a worship service?"))
p
```

[image]

The graph above is produced from the raw data. However, it is sometimes
convenient to produce graphs from summarized data, especially if one
needs control over statistical functions. Below is transformation of dsN
into ds that contains only the values that are actually mapped on the
graph above:

````
require(dplyr)
ds<- dsN %.%
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(attendF)) %.%
  dplyr::group_by(yearF,attendF) %.%
  dplyr::summarize(count = sum(attendF)) %.%
  dplyr::mutate(total = sum(count),
              percent= count/total)
head(ds,10)

    Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
    Groups: yearF

       yearF              attendF count total percent
    1   2001                Never    18   373 0.04826
    2   2001        Once or Twice    36   373 0.09651
    3   2001 Less than once/month    30   373 0.08043
    4   2001     About once/month    32   373 0.08579
    5   2001    About twice/month    40   373 0.10724
    6   2001      About once/week    90   373 0.24129
    7   2001   Several times/week   119   373 0.31903
    8   2001             Everyday     8   373 0.02145
    9   2002                Never    11   355 0.03099
    10  2002        Once or Twice    44   355 0.12394

# verify
summarize(filter(ds, yearF==2001), should.be.one=sum(percent))
```

    Source: local data frame [1 x 2]

      yearF should.be.one
    1  2001             1
````

#### Question:

How would one re-create a graph from above using this summary dataset
`ds`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, part of the problem is that your summarizing is incorrect. You need to leave the NA values in there if you want to properly account for them in the total. Perhaps try

```
ds<- dsN %.%
  dplyr::group_by(yearF,attendF) %.%
  dplyr::summarize(count = length(attendF)) %.%
  dplyr::mutate(total = sum(count, na.rm=T),
              percent= count/total)
```

Then to use the summarized data, you only slightly need to change your first two lines

```
p<- ggplot( ds, aes(x=yearF, y=percent, fill=attendF))  #  keeping NA in calculations
p<- p+ geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

Note that we add a specific `y` value and we tell geom_bar to use `stat="identity"` which means to use the actual `y` values we supplied as the height. And they they will produce the same image

[image]

Comment: You are right. I'm still hazy on dplyr. The NA issue is not a wrong/right, but stems from the goal of analysis ( i describe in in the update). The ggplot syntax was just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer from Comment 1

As @MrFlick pointed out, the error was in the computation formulas in summarize(). However, whether to leave missing values in the calculation of the total is a meaningful research decision. 
If we want to leave `NA` in the calculation of the total:

```
ds<- dsN %.%
#   dplyr::filter(!is.na(attendF)) %.%   # comment out to count NA in the total
  dplyr::group_by(yearF,attendF) %.%
  dplyr::summarize(count = length( attendF)) %.%
  dplyr::mutate(total = sum(count),
              percent= count/total)
head(ds,10)

     Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
    Groups: yearF

       yearF              attendF count total percent
    1   2001                Never    23   100    0.23
    2   2001        Once or Twice     9   100    0.09
    3   2001 Less than once/month    16   100    0.16
    4   2001     About once/month    11   100    0.11
    5   2001    About twice/month     3   100    0.03
    6   2001      About once/week    21   100    0.21
    7   2001   Several times/week     9   100    0.09
    8   2001             Everyday     3   100    0.03
    9   2001                   NA     5   100    0.05
    10  2002                Never    17   100    0.17
```

Missing values are used in the calculation of total responses to show
the natural attrition in the study.

```
p<- ggplot( ds, aes(x=yearF, y=percent, fill=attendF))  #  keeping NA in calculations
p<- p+ geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
p<- p+ scale_fill_manual(values = attcol8,
                         name="Response category" )
p<- p+ scale_y_continuous("Prevalence: proportion of total",
                          limits=c(0, 1),
                          breaks=c(.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1))
p<- p+ scale_x_discrete("Waves of measurement",
                        limits=as.character(c(2000:2005)))
p<- p+ labs(title=paste0("In the past year, how often have you attended a worship service?"))
p
```

[image]

However, assumming that attrition is not significantly associated with
the outcome measure, it would be of interest to see how relative
prevalence of response endorsement changes over time, or perhaps stays
in an equilibrium. For this we need to remove missing values from the
calculation of the total of responses:

```
ds<- dsN %.%
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(attendF)) %.%   # comment out to count NA in the total
  dplyr::group_by(yearF,attendF) %.%
  dplyr::summarize(count = length( attendF)) %.%
  dplyr::mutate(total = sum(count),
              percent= count/total)
head(ds,10)

    Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
    Groups: yearF

       yearF              attendF count total percent
    1   2001                Never    23    95 0.24211
    2   2001        Once or Twice     9    95 0.09474
    3   2001 Less than once/month    16    95 0.16842
    4   2001     About once/month    11    95 0.11579
    5   2001    About twice/month     3    95 0.03158
    6   2001      About once/week    21    95 0.22105
    7   2001   Several times/week     9    95 0.09474
    8   2001             Everyday     3    95 0.03158
    9   2002                Never    17    90 0.18889
    10  2002        Once or Twice    23    90 0.25556
```

Graph reflects this accordingly:

```
p<- ggplot( ds, aes(x=yearF, y=percent, fill=attendF))  #  keeping NA in calculations
p<- p+ geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
p<- p+ scale_fill_manual(values = attcol8,
                         name="Response category" )
p<- p+ scale_y_continuous("Prevalence: proportion of total",
                          limits=c(0, 1),
                          breaks=c(.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1))
p<- p+ scale_x_discrete("Waves of measurement",
                        limits=as.character(c(2000:2005)))
p<- p+ labs(title=paste0("In the past year, how often have you attended a worship service?"))
p
```

[image]

Thanks, @MrFlick!